# Is it possible to define a child from a struct and set it members?

Tags: c++, struct

Suppose we have the following structure defined:

```
struct MyStrusture{
    unsigned char code;
    unsigned char * data;
    int size;
};
```

Is that possible to define a new struct which inherits from MyStructure and set its members at the same time? Something like this:

```
struct MyStrusture1 : MyStrusture{
        code=1;
        data={1,2,3};
        size=3;
    };
```

I have tried it but it does not get compiled I have to redefine each member in child structure. How could I reach parent members in the derived structure??

By the way, My opinion is to use MyStrusture as a function parameter so I could write the signature in this form `method1(MyStructure)` when I call the function I can use MyStructure1 or 2 or etc. Is this a standard way or I should use another technique?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It's not the same in c and in c++ they are different languages, please pick a language. And `data={1,2,3};` this is invalid even without the struct.

Answer (score 6):

I assume your question is only about C++, not C, because you derive from your base structure. I'll also assume C++11.

In order to get what you want, you can use the following syntax:

```
struct MyStrusture1 : MyStrusture
{
    MyStrusture1() : MyStrusture({ 1, nullptr, 3 }) {}
};
```

Note that I initialized your `data` pointer to `nullptr` to explain the base concept.

Initializing it with some contents the way you want to, now that's trickier. A naive approach would be:

```
struct MyStrusture1 : MyStrusture
{
    MyStrusture1() : MyStrusture({ 1, new unsigned char[3] { 1, 2, 3 }, 3 }) {}
};
```

But this creates all kinds of problems, for example who is supposed to delete `data` and when. My guess is that you don't want dynamic allocation at all, and the pointer in your base structure should actually be an array:

```
struct MyStrusture{
    unsigned char code;
    unsigned char data[3];
    int size;
};

struct MyStrusture1 : MyStrusture
{
    MyStrusture1() : MyStrusture({ 1, { 1, 2, 3 }, 3 }) {}
};
```

If the size should be variable, `std::vector` can be used:

```
#include <vector>

struct MyStrusture{
    unsigned char code;
    std::vector<unsigned char> data;
    int size;
};

struct MyStrusture1 : MyStrusture
{
    MyStrusture1() : MyStrusture({ 1, { 1, 2, 3 }, 3 }) {}
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But Maybe I didn't ask my question properly. I actually, just need constant. Some kind of categorized constants. But all of them should have a same type so I can use them as parameters. I do not need dynamic allocation. I need them to be constant.

Comment: @a.toraby: It's not entirely clear to me what you really want. What are "categorized constants"? The variables in your base struct are not "parameters" in the C++ sense of the word. In any case, if you need a constant-sized collection of elements, a pointer member is almost certainly the wrong choice. Use an array (or perhaps even `std::array`).

Answer (score 1):

In c++ you can just do it this way

```
class MyStruct
{
public:
    MyStruct();

private:
    unsigned char code;
    unsigned char *data;
    int size;
};

MyStruct::MyStruct() :
    code(1)
  , data(new unsigned char[3])
  , size(3)
{
    data[0] = 1;
    data[1] = 2;
    data[2] = 3;
}
```

Comment: How about just recalling the structure  within your new structure?  Such as `struct MyStructure1{ MyStructure somename; };`

Comment: @Pita: I've never heard the expression "to recall a structure". What do you mean?

Comment: @Pita: By the way, your example is indeed conceptually similar to public inheritance and may be closer to what the OP really needs.

Comment: @Christian Hackle "to recall a structure" is my trademark terminology ;) I am bad in remembering names and terminology so I make it up as I go. My coworkers mostly get what I mean...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it using a *constructor*:

```
struct MyStrusture{
    unsigned char code;
    unsigned char * data;
    int size;
};

struct MyStrusture1 : MyStrusture{
    MyStrusture1(); // the constructor
};
```

Then define the `MyStrusture1()` constructor in a .cpp file, and initialize the data members there:

```
MyStrusture1::MyStrusture1()
:   MyStrusture { 1, new unsigned char[3] { 1, 2, 3 }, 3 }
{
}
```